# jQuery/HTML resizing horizontal scroll when changing tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have 3 HTML tabs in my HTML markup like following:

```
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active"> </div> 
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in"> </div> 
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade in active"> </div>
```

The problem here is that almost always the home tab is larger ( the height of the page is always bigger) than other two menu tabs , menu1 and menu2. What I would like to do here is to set the height of the scroller accordingly to what the content of the tab is... I was thinking I could do this via jQuery or somehow via CSS?

I tried doing it with plain javascript like this:

```
 $("#home").click(function(){
        $(this).toggle();
    });
    $("#menu1").click(function(){
        $(this).toggle();
    });
    $("#menu2").click(function(){
        $(this).toggle();
    });
```

But in this case nothing happens...

P.S. A case would go like:

Home tab has bunch of content and it creates a horizontal scroll all the way down.

Menu1 tab has only 50px height let's say. And when I click on it, I can still see empty space that is missing (left from home tab)...

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Why do you `.toggle()` twice?

Comment: @PatrickMlr sry I'ts a mistype, I forgot to remove it , it wasn't there in the original jQuery code =)

Comment: Any chance you can replicate the problem in JSFiddle or SOs own StackSnippets?

Comment: Does your "Home"-content have a fixed height?

Comment: @PatrickMlr no, it's dynamic... the height gets set based upon how many Items I have in the ViewBag and how much elements the table has...

Comment: @User987 So you have already a function which calculate the height?

Comment: @PatrickMlr Actually no, the only thing that I've did was used these classes above: fade in tab-pane and active... Everything else besides that is dynamic. P.S. These are bootstrap classes

Comment: @User987 Any chance to replicate the problem on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or use the Stackoverflow Snippet tool?

Comment: @PatrickMlr I managed to find the "source" of the problem... Looks like these "active" classes are messing things up.. I only must set "active" class to the specific tab when it is actually clicked and then reload the tab's HTML. How could I do that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137449/discussion-between-patrick-mlr-and-user987).